# Flag apron shows superfluous closing anchor tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools

I awoke this morning to a spam flag on a site I moderate, and noticed this when I went to read the post.

[image: Example image]

Notice `answered</a>`, which I imagine isn't meant to have the `</a>` there.

I also confirmed that this displays `asked</a>` for other types of flags (namely, closed without comment).

I looked around for a duplicate of this but can't seem to find it, so maybe it's a recent change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (build rev - OCD alert - `2015.2.*.3112` on meta, `2015.2.*.2332` on sites).